# django serving static css files

Tags: django, django-templates

I am relatively new to Django development.I have a css file inside a /static/css directory.

When I try to run the url no CSS is applied to my template. the python manage.py runserver window shows following error

[01/Jan/2013 20:00:40] "GET /home/prat/PROJECT_ROOT/SOURCE_ROOT/static/css/Style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 2207

Can someone please point me how to debug this. I have read multiple stackoverflow questions and added the following setting in my settings.py.

```
PROJECT_R = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__name__))
PROJEECT_R = PROJECT_R + "../"
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_R, "static")
STATIC_URL = 'static/'

.
├── manage.py
├── README
├── SOURCE_ROOT
│   ├── __init__.py
│   ├── __init__.pyc
│   ├── settings.py
│   ├── settings.pyc
│   ├── urls.py
│   ├── urls.pyc
│   ├── wsgi.py
│   └── wsgi.pyc
├── static
│   ├── css
│   │   ├── README
│   │   └── Style.css
│   ├── images
│   │   └── README
│   └── js
│       └── README
├── template
│   ├── base.html
```

Comment: Is `django.contrib.staticfiles` in `INSTALLED_APPS`?

Comment: yes it is present there.

Comment: my other query is the path i have specified in that i have hard coded the path of the css and it still doesn't work "  <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/home/prat/PROJECT_ROOT/SOURCE_ROOT/static/css/Style.css" />

Comment: Edited my answer to include that bit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I usually go about managing dynamic project root:

```
from os.path import dirname, realpath, join
PROJECT_ROOT = dirname(realpath(__file__))
```

And then further below, the static root:

```
STATIC_ROOT = join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'static/')
```

And then you reference static files like so:

```
{{ STATIC_URL }}css/Style.css
```

EDIT:

See [the documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/) for more information.

Comment: I am using Django 1.4.3 which creates the structure like /myproj/myproj/settings.py. The static directory which contains the css lies under /myproj/static that is the reason i added the ../. Do you think it is not needed?

Comment: If you say `os.path.dirname(some_directory)`, it selects the parent directory, so you do not need `../`.

Comment: Thanks . I am just trying is now. BTW. Do you know why hard coded path is not working for me?

Comment: When you are serving static files, you are not dealing with actual filesystem paths in URL. You are dealing with URLs that Django maps to paths internally. That's what `STATIC_URL` is for. So basically, all static files end up in `example.com/STATIC_URL/*`. Django kindly provides the `STATIC_URL` variable in your templates, so you can use it to reference the static file URLs as demonstarated in my answer.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thanks explains why it is not working for me when i hard coded it.

Comment: Keep in mind that, generally, when you need to hard-code something, it's usually just bad design. Another rare possiblity is that it's a bad Django design, but that can be fixed with a bug report (and, optionally, a patch).

Comment: Thanks you very much. I am another query poping up, while i am fixing this. when the setting.py is invoked what is path. i did python manage.py shell and then in the python prompt i did from django.conf import settings. if i print settings.PROJECT_R it prints "/home/prat/PROJECT_ROOT/SOURCE_ROOT" while the setting file is lyin g inside "/home/prat/PROJECT_ROOT/SOURCE_ROOT/SOURCE_ROOT/"

Comment: You had two variables. One is `PROJECT_R`, and another is `PROJEECT_R` (with double E). My suggestion was to fix the other one. You probably fixed the first one, which is wrong.

Comment: i did the changes suggested by you. Looks like there is still some problem. in my webpage view source i see path as " <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="static/css/Style.css" /> rather than http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/css/Style.css. CSS is still not applied

Comment: Change `STATIC_URL` to `/static/`.

Comment: thanks!!, i will carefully make all these suggestion. I will add my finding once it is done. Thank you very much on helping me out.I will update the comment once i got success.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22014/discussion-between-bvukelic-and-david)