# blank django project serving static CSS file

Tags: python, django, windows

I have created a new django project using the command

```
django-admin startproject mysite
```

this created the basic django directory structure. I then added a directory called `static` under `/mysite/mysite/static` and then created `style.css` within this.

```
PS C:\Users\Danny\Desktop\django-test> tree /f
Folder PATH listing
Volume serial number is B069-3254
C:.
└───mysite
    │   db.sqlite3
    │   manage.py
    │
    └───mysite
        │   settings.py
        │   settings.pyc
        │   urls.py
        │   urls.pyc
        │   wsgi.py
        │   wsgi.pyc
        │   __init__.py
        │   __init__.pyc
        │
        └───static
                style.css
```

**settings.py (part of)**

```
STATIC_ROOT = 'C:/Users/Danny/Desktop/django-test/mysite/mysite/static'
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

I then run the server using

```
python manage.py runserver
```

and navigate to http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/style.css and expect to see my stylesheet, however I am presented with `404 Page Not Found`

I have read the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/static-files/) and I am struggling to see any steps I have missed? I just want it to work locally, and I am not bothered about a production environment at the moment.

Comment: Think this should help : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14116157/django-serving-static-css-files

Comment: I saw that it didn't help.

Comment: what is your STATIC_ROOT setting set to?

Comment: Did you set up static files settings?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, on your `yourprojectfolder/settings.py` you have to set up a couple of variables:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
PROJECT_FOLDER = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(PROJECT_FOLDER, "static")                                  
STATIC_URL = '/static/'                                                                                                                

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles"), )              

STATICFILES_FINDERS = (                                                         
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',                      
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',                  
)
```

And basically, that tells Django to look for your files in the folder `staticfiles/` on the same directory as `manage.py`. So put your `.css` files there and that's pretty much it.

Comment: Just added that to settings.py, renamed my `mysite/static` to `mysite/staticfiles` and it still doesn't show my css file at http://127.0.0.1:8000/static/style.css

Comment: That's pretty weird. I just created a `test` project and followed each one of the instructions that I gave you and I can serve the file, let me double check

Comment: Hold on managed to get it working my adding a top level folder

Comment: It works at the very top level under a `staticfiles` directory, thanks

Comment: Haha yes sir, it's at the very top level. Glad you have it working now :-)

Comment: your answer actually shows the staticfiles directory is in the same as settings.py

Comment: You're totally right! pardon me! but fortunately you get it to work, almost on your own